# Show Message Box

Tags: c#

```
namespace WindowsFormsAppEmailClient
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    MailMessage MyMsg = new MailMessage();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SmtpClient MyServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

        //defining global MyMsg so we use it in attachment button
        // MailMessage MyMsg = new MailMessage();

        MyMsg.From = new MailAddress(  "asharkashif2@gmail.com");

        MyMsg.To.Add(tbTo.Text);

        if (tbcc.Text != "")
        {
            MyMsg.CC.Add(tbcc.Text);
        }

        MyMsg.Subject = tbSub.Text;

        //message = body

        MyMsg.Body = tbMsg.Text;

        MyServer.EnableSsl = true;

        //Credentials used for defining User Name  + Password

        MyServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("asharkashif2@gmail.com", "03456016286");
        MyServer.Send(MyMsg);
    }

    private void btnAtt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        Attachment myFile = new Attachment(openFileDialog1.FileName);

        MyMsg.Attachments.Add(myFile);
    }
 }
}
```

Question Is : I want to show Message Box of Success when the Email Send successfully. Please help

Comment: Please tell me you didn't post your real credentials in the code.

Comment: Dear Simply I Need to "Display Message" of "Success" when I Click to Send Email

Comment: Yup, its real, and the backup email address wasnt too hard to figure out, so you might want to change your password now ;)

Comment: it is changed, My Question still pending

Comment: @SwDevMan81 although I understand it was a serious faux pas for the OP to post his actual credentials, it is still illegal to log in to their account without permission...

Comment: @EvanL Just trying to make the OP aware in case it was real.  Someone less honest might actually do something malicious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code and the fact that you posted your actual credentials on a public forum, I will assume you just want a synchronous solution and want to show a message box after your (blocking) call to `MyServer.Send();`

wrap your send in a `try/catch` block:

```
// The program will attempt to send a message
try
{
    MySever.Send(MyMsg);
    MessageBox.Show("Message sent successfully");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Whoops there was an error sending the message, better tell the user what happened.
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Message Failed To send because: {0}", ex.message);
}
```

If this is not working, then you will need to add some context to your question, such as any errors or exceptions you are seeing.

The "right" way to do this though would be to do `MyServer.SendAsync(MyMsg)` and then have a callback listening to the `SendCompleted` event provided to you by the `SMTPClient` class:

[MSDN Example of Async Mail Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @AsharKashif No problem honey ;)  Please mark my answer as the answer by clicking the Green checkmark below the up/down vote buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [MessageBox.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)??